# Check XML for the existence of a specific key

Tags: xml, coldfusion

In the following XML I want to see if there is element called "errors"

```
<cfxml variable="sXML">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<createTransactionResponse>
   <messages>
      <message>
         <text>
            <XmlText>The transaction was unsuccessful.</XmlText>
         </text>
       </message>
     </messages>
   <transactionResponse>
     <errors>
       <error>
         <errorText>
           <XmlText>The credit card number is invalid.</XmlText>
         </errorText>
       </error>
     </errors>
   </transactionResponse>
 </createTransactionResponse>
</cfxml>
```

To see if node "errors" is present I used:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(sXML, "errors")>
```

But it comes back `false` (If the transaction was successful the XML doesn't have node "errors"). What am I doing wrong or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dump the xml stucture with `<cfdump var="#sXML#">`, it shows that "errors" is a child node, several levels down:

[image: Dump of sXML nodes]

You can reference it through the parent structures. Assuming the xml always contains the parent nodes "createTransactionResponse" and "transactionResponse", use:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(sXML.createTransactionResponse.transactionResponse, "errors")>
    Found
<cfelse>
    Not Found
</cfif>
```

Comment: That was it.  The actual XML is a mile long. No xPath I can use?

Comment: Sure you can use [xmlSearch](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/xmlsearch.html) and test the length of the returned array. If it's 0, you know the node/key wasn't found.  For example `resultArray = xmlSearch(sXML, ".//errors")`. Though that's just an example. Since "errors" is pretty common, may want to use a more precise search string.